# Linear Transformations preserving linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V, W$ are vector spaces and $ T: V \to W $  is a linear transformation.

$v_1, v_2, ... , v_k \in V$.

Prove or disprove:

If $(T(v_1)), ... , T(v_k))$ is linearly dependent, then $( v_1, v_2, ... , v_k)$ is linearly dependent.

We know that if this was the other way around and $( v_1, v_2, ... , v_k)$ was linearly dependent, then from the linearity of $T(v)$ we can prove $(T(v_1)), ... , T(v_k))$ is linearly dependent.

But is this true for the other way around, making it an 'iff' statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get infinitely many counter examples by taking $V,W$ such that $\dim W < \dim V=n,$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in V$ linearly independent with $k\geq n.$ Then $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_k)$ are linearly dependent being $k$ elements in a space with dimension $<k.$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true consider  the zero map. $(v_1)$ is linear independent if $v_1\neq 0$ but $T(v_1)=0$ is linearly dependent.